# Expected value of function of continuous-time random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk, renewal-processes

Suppose $X_t$ is simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ in continuous time. Time between jumps is distributed as ${\rm Exp}(\lambda)$, $X(0) = 0$.

I am interested in calculation of $\mathbb{E} e^{X_t}$ and in general $\mathbb{E} f\left(X_t\right)$.

I do not know where to start, since $\mathbb{E} e^{X_t}$ is the sum of a random number of random variables.

Please advise me where I can read about this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks! I have edited the question. The problem is that I don't even know where to start thinking about the problem. So I'm asking for an advice or papers on this issue, not an explicit solution.

Comment: Hint: The number of jumps you take on $[0,t]$ is a $\text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ random variable.

Comment: @MatthewH. As I understand, we can decompose $\mathbb{E}e^{X_t}$ into the following sum: 

$\mathbb{E}e^{X_t} =
\sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty} e^x P(X_t = x)  =
\sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty} e^x \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} P(N_{jumps} = n)P\left(X(n) = x \right). $


Using Poisson distribution we can get:
$\sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty} e^x \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}P\left(X(n) = x \right).$

But what to do now?

Comment: I suggest you use total law of expectation: $$\mathbb{E}(e^{X_t})=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}(e^{X_t}|N_t)\right)$$ Try to show that $$\mathbb{E}(e^{X_t}|N_t)=\left(\cosh(1)\right)^{N_t}$$ and go from there.

Comment: @MatthewH. thank you very much!
I've posted the answer. Maybe you could suggest books or courses on CTRW in 101 style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @MatthewH.!

$$\mathbb E (e^{X_t}) = \mathbb E \left(\mathbb E (e^{X_t}|N_t)\right), $$
where $N_t$ is number of jumps during time $t$.

$$\mathbb E (e^{X_t}|N_t) = \sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty}e^x\cdot P(X_n = x),$$
where $X_n$ is sum of $n$ jumps.

$$P(X_n = x) = \frac 12 P(X_{n-1} = x-1) + \frac 12 P(X_{n-1} = x+1).$$

Therefore

$$\mathbb E (e^{X_t}|N_t) = \sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty}e^x\cdot P(X_n = x) = \\= \frac12 \left( \sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty}e^x\cdot P(X_{n-1} = x-1) + \sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty}e^x\cdot P(X_{n-1} = x+1) \right) = \\ 
= \frac12 \left( \sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty}e^{x+1}\cdot P(X_{n-1} = x) + \sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty}e^{x-1}\cdot P(X_{n-1} = x) \right) = \\ =
\frac12 \left( e \sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty}e^{x}\cdot P(X_{n-1} = x) + e^{-1}\sum\limits_{x = -\infty}^{\infty}e^{x}\cdot P(X_{n-1} = x) \right) = \\ = \frac{e^{-1} + e}2 \cdot \mathbb E (e^{X_t}|N_t-1) = \dots = \left( \frac{e^{-1} + e}2 \right)^{N_t} = (\cosh 1 )^{N_t}. $$

Going back to $\mathbb E (e^{X_t})$:

$$\mathbb E (e^{X_t}) = \mathbb E \left(\mathbb E (e^{X_t}|N_t)\right)  
= \mathbb E \left( (\cosh 1 )^{N_t} \right) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( \cosh 1 \right)^k \cdot e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!} = \\ =  e^{-\lambda t }\cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(\lambda t \cosh 1)^k}{k!} = e^{-\lambda t} \cdot e^{\lambda t\cosh 1} = e^{ \lambda t (\cosh 1 - 1)}. $$